# how to modify output of - echo stats | nc <ip> <port>

Tags: bash, opentsdb, netcat

```
TSD_HOST=localhost
TSD_PORT=4242
COLLECTION_INTERVAL=60

nc -z $TSD_HOST $TSD_PORT >/dev/null || exit 13

while :; do
  echo stats || exit
    sleep $COLLECTION_INTERVAL
done | nc $TSD_HOST $TSD_PORT
```

Output:

```
tsd.hbase.rpcs 1389058717 2037068142 type=put host=x
tsd.hbase.rpcs 1389058717 0 type=rowLock host=x
tsd.hbase.rpcs 1389058717 17 type=openScanner host=x
tsd.hbase.rpcs 1389058717 29 type=scan host=x
tsd.hbase.rpcs.batched 1389058717 5258656 host=x
```

Above is the default `tcollector` script that comes with `opentsdb`. I want to add an extra tag to every element being printed out; ex:

```
tsd.hbase.rpcs 1389058717 2037068142 type=put host=x  cluster=y
```

I want to append `cluster=y` to every element of stats. But I can't find a good shortcut to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Append "`| awk '{print $0 " cluster=y"}'`" to the end of the "`done | nc $TSD_HOST $TSD_PORT`" line (or, if you don't want to modify the script, just do `tcollector | awk '{print $0 " cluster=y"}`).

Comment: works like a charm. can you explain me how echo stats exactly works ? does nc $TSD_HOST $TSD_PORT grab stats from the socket line by line and print it ? is there a good read on this ? only info i saw abt it was with relation to memcached. Thanks a ton!

Comment: "`echo stats`" just prints out the word "`stats`" followed by a newline.  This is then piped to `nc`, which sends it across the internet to `$TSD_HOST`, and then `nc` sends back whatever the remote server's response to `stats` is.